# Droidgap ERROR no such file or directory in Phonegap Android App

Tags: android, cordova

I'm creating an AndroidApp using Phonegap, but when i run the emulator i got the following error:

```
 droidgap:48:in ``': No such file or directory
      android create project -t 7 -k be.progone.test -a PG1 -n PG1 -p E:/baud/work/Mobile/Pr_Eclipse/PG1/build (Errno::ENOENT) 
      from droidgap:48:in create_android'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Android SDK tools path to the system.

```
Eg: C:\Program Files\Android SDK\tools
```

Answer (score 2):

cehck local.properties file in your FrameworkFolder, pointing to yout android sdk dir